# I have just installed CentOS 6 & Plesk 11.5, are there and security / email settings I need to change?

Tags: centos, plesk

I've installed CentOS 6 & Plesk 11.5.
Are there any SSH changes I need to make to improve security, setup mail servers, optimise email settings etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you worried about SSH, you can change SSH port from 22 to some other, forbid root login via SSH, setup and configure sudo and google around linux security best practice.
Also, You can change Plesk security policy at Tools & Settings -> Security Policy, maybe you want to change "Minimum password strength"

If Plesk already installed that you already have Postfix, which is installing by default.